# flutter alert dialog not updating from outside the function

Tags: flutter, flutter-alertdialog

i want to make a download progress message inside the alert dialog but state not updating inside the the modal
the is the download function using dio

```
downloadBook() async {
    Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    var response = await dio.download(widget.bookModel.acf.bookLink,
        tempDir.path + '/books/' + widget.bookModel.title.rendered + '.epub',
        options: Options(
          responseType: ResponseType.bytes,
        ), onReceiveProgress: (actualbytes, totalbytes) {
      var percenatge = actualbytes / totalbytes * 100;
      _percentageBar = percenatge / 100;
      setState(() {
        downloadMessage = 'Downloading... ${percenatge.floor()} %';
      });
    });
  }
```

and this is the alert dialogue function

```
void _showDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: new Text("Alert!!"),
          content: new Text(downloadMessage),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new FlatButton(
              child: new Text("OK"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

and i made call like this inside the text button but the message stuck on 0% and not updated;

```
onPressed: () {
        // _showDialog(context);
        downloadBook();
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            String contentText = "Content of Dialog";
            return StatefulBuilder(
              builder: (context, setState) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  title: new Text("Alert!!"),
                  content: new Text(downloadMessage),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    new FlatButton(
                      child: new Text("OK"),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            );
          },
        );
      },
```

Comment: Hello, could you solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

You can use

> StatefullBuilder

widget top of your alert dialog and pass

> setState

to it where you call it.

In this way you can access to State from outside.

Answer (score -1):

As I understood from your question, you are trying to have a different state for your alert dialog, so I will just update your code regarding the alertDialog and you can do what you want after that.

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    String contentText = "Content of Dialog";
    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (context, setState) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: new Text("Alert!!"),
          content: new Text(downloadMessage),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new FlatButton(
              child: new Text("OK"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  },
);
```

So you can use setState for any progress you want inside.

Comment: not working state stuck not changing ... i update the code up

Comment: As I explained the alert has its own state right now, so you can use setState in case you want to update it. @FLASHTUBE